# Login Into a router using Python

Tags: python, sockets, networking, router

I need to log into the router using python and http method due to the fact that i can't use telnet or SSH with it.
is it possible ? i looked and found different approaches but all just lead to errors or just fetch html page of the login page and doesn't log into the router.
if anyone can explain to me how to do it, i will appreciate that.

also if the ip used with https not http, how to bypass the Warning Page (which requires to press a button in order to enter a router) ?.

below is the codes i tried :

```
import requests

url = 'http://your-router-ip/login'
payload = {
    'username': 'your_username',
    'password': 'your_password'
}

response = requests.post(url, data=payload)

# Check if login was successful
if response.status_code == 200:
    print("Login successful")
else:
    print("Login failed")
```

another approach

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

with requests.session() as session:
    page = session.get('http://192.168.0.1')
    html = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
    print(html)
    csrf_token = html.find('input',{'name':'csrf_token'})['value']
    data_to_login = {'username':'admin','password':'admin', 'csrf_token': csrf_token}

    t = session.post('http://192.168.0.1',data_to_login)
    print(t.text)
```

Comment: If your router has a Web-GUI (which it likely has) then it should be possible to use Python to log into it. The details depend though on how exactly the GUI is implemented, i.e. there is no method which is generic for all routers.